# Nuxtjs store undefined in middleware on refresh

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vuex

I'm using nuxt js for my web app, I need to keep the store when I refresh the page, even in middleware or the page itself.
I'm using vuex-persistedstate;

```
import createPersistedState from "vuex-persistedstate";

    export default ({ store }) => {
      if (process.client) {
        window.onNuxtReady(() => {
          createPersistedState({})(store);
        });
      }
    };
```

One of the solutions that I tried is to use cookies in the store, but my data is very huge and I need it in the local storage.

I think it's something related to SSR or server middleware, I tried a lot to figure out how to solve it, but nth is working.

Comment: Have you tried to store your data in the local storage or session storage of the client?

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible because we are not able to access localStorage when component is rendering on the server side. You should either turn off ssr to use localStorage or try to reduce the size of your data to put it in cookies.